# Is there a concise way to do conditionals where the 'falsy' value isn't displayed in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I know I can do:

```html
{value ? value: ''}
```

But having to display the `''` for the falsy value is repetitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For falsiness you can use:

```html
{value || ''}
```

(Note that this can lead to undesirable results depending on use case, e.g. a value of `0` will not be rendered.)

For nullish values, the shortest would be to use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing):

```html
{value ?? ''}
```

This is a bit of a newer feature, build tools like Vite can probably compile it down to a ternary.